# How to scale text's size along with TextBox's size in the WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, window, scaling

When I resize Window of the WPF application, all textboxes are also resized. The problem is that size of the text in the textboxes doesn't change. How can I achieve scaling the size of the text along with the size of the textboxes?

Edit: Actually, it is scaling, but I want to make text bigger. So, the height of the font should be close to height of the textbox. How this can be achieved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

maybe something like this will help

```
<Viewbox> 
    <TextBox/> 
</Viewbox>
```

Just play with the maring property of the TextBox to get what you want

Comment: Actually, I satisfied with size of the textbox. I wanted to increase font of the text inside the textbox.

Comment: This will change the fontsize inside the textbox... Just place it inside a viewbox and you will see

Comment: When I added Viewbox around textbox, the textbox somehow moved from the bottom of the window to the top. Why is that so?

Comment: Probably because your margins and/or other positioning properties are still set for the textbox instead of the viewbox

Answer (score 1):

I Think You Can Use This Code:\

In SizeChange Event In TextBox

```
private void TextBox_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e) 
{
    Size n = e.NewSize;
    Size p = e.PreviousSize;
    double l = n.Width / p.Width;
    if (l!=double.PositiveInfinity)
    {
        textbox1.FontSize = textbox1.FontSize * l;
    }
}
```